# Corcel / Laravel Eloquent Model get multiple post_types results | WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

My goal is to get all posts of three different custom post types via Corcel. It is important that i use the Post-Model and not three custom Models, because i need to sort and filter afterwards.

My approach - which does not work - is based on a where function. But it does not work. Any ideas how to achieve what i am looking for?

```
$all_posts_sorted = Post::published()->newest()->get()->where( 'post_type', '=', [ 'post_type_1', 'post_type_2', 'post_type_3' ] );
```

If there is another way how to combine three Models (PostType1, PostType2,...) into one new Model - i would be fine with this too.

Comment: The `where()` method doesn't match against multiple values (an array). Use the `whereIn()` method. Also, `->get()` returns a `Collection`, in your case, every record from the database, then uses PHP logic to filter. Consider putting your `whereIn()` before `get()` to increase performance, as it will use database logic to filter the value before committing to PHP memory.

Comment: Damn - that was fast! Thanks a lot. I will update the question with the result.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Answer thanks to @tim-lewis (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis)

```
$post_types = [ 'post_type_1', 'post_type_2', 'post_type_3' ];
$all_posts_sorted = Post::published()->newest()->whereIn( 'post_type', $post_types )->get();
```